# How to include RMarkdown file in r package?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm in the process of creating a package in R and I also want to include an R Markdown file. This RMarkdown template contains functions from my package, and is rendered to an html document via knitr.

The goal is to regularly run a function (via a cronjob) that renders the RMarkdown file in order to produce weekly reports.

How is it possible to add such files to an R package (like a .Rmd) and reference the .Rmd when making a function call to render said template, particularly since using `use_data(myrmarkdown.Rmd)` won't achieve the desired result.

Comment: I closed this as it really as a double of a dozen existing questions regarding 'how do I include $FOO' in my package, and the answer always is 'below `inst/`'.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel While that may be obvious to you, as you have more structural meta-knowledge, the answer below was precisely what I was looking for, and the linked post would not have answered my question. 
In particular, accessing an Rmd (different than simply calling `data(x)` was key.

Comment: @DanielEgan, glad it helped but the site really does not get better when we write the same things X times under different labels.  For this, the answer is essentially "use `system.file()`" -- so just try eg `system.file("doc", "knitr-intro.Rmd", package="knitr")` which *no matter where and how you installed knitr* will provide you with a full path the file -- as it came from `inst/doc/knitr-intro.Rmd` and R can then compute these things.  This is pretty well documented (if hard to find at first).

Comment: I voted to reopen because 1) this use case is different from the duplicate in that the file must be accessed by `path`, not using `data()`, 2) the answers to the linked question are vague and over-reliant on reading outside sources. While reading the sources that the linked answers suggest might help you figure out what to do, they certainly don't answer this question.

Comment: I agree that this is sufficiently different from existing questions. This sort of response is the sort of thing that can make SO very hostile to newer users.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

When you are creating an *R* package, you will have a directory tree containing the following (among others) in the root directory of the package: `DESCRIPTION`, `NAMESPACE`, and the `R/` directory. If you also have an `inst/` directory, then everything within that directory is copied verbatim to within your package directory, excluding the `inst/`.

For instance, if your package directory looks like this:

```
+- DESCRIPTION
+- NAMESPACE
+- inst/
|  \- rmd/
|     \- file.Rmd
\- R/
   +- file1.R
   +- file2.R
   \- file3.R
```

Then when you build the package and install it, you'll find in the following in your package library:

```
+- DESCRIPTION
+- INDEX
+- NAMESPACE
+- rmd/
|  \- file.Rmd
\- R/
   +- packagename
   +- packagename.rdb
   \- packagename.rdx
```

(Other files/directories are created during the process, I'm ignoring them for simplicity.)

The last piece of information you need to know is "how do I access this file once it is installed?" Since some systems install the *R* library in different directories, and on top of that users often install packages within a personal *R* library, you cannot know a priori where to look Enter `system.file`:

```
system.file("rmd", "file.Rmd", package = "packagename")
## [1] "c:/R/R-3.1.3/library/packagename/rmd/file.Rmd"
```

This can be used for the whole Rmd file. I use it for company-specific templates for Rmd-rendered documents. That is, I look for "include" files to personalize the LaTeX so that the rendered PDF has headers/footers and is styled the way we want. This step requires writing a function that replaces the `pdf_document` (for example) in the Rmd YAML header, but that's covered well at [rmarkdown.rstudio.com](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com).

Comment: thanks a lot @r2evans, this was very helpful and was just the answer I was looking for, appreciate it!

Comment: @Konrad, I don't mind the edit (I like its straight-forward-ness), but I've never had a problem using forward or even mixed slashes on windows, and the forward slash is the right answer for every other OS (on which I've used R). Once I learned windows' R works just fine with forward-slashes, I rarely if ever put backslashes in my paths (and often over-ride `fsep="/"`.

Comment: @r2evans It's good to know, I was thinking it could be problematic hence but I may be wrong if you've never experienced any issues. I always try to use `file.path`, just to be on a safe side but it may be it's overcautious