# R package to knit a markdown document given some data

Tags: r, package, markdown, r-markdown

I am writing a basic R package that reads in data from a user specified database and spits out a markdown report with predefined graphs and tables etc. I have placed the .Rmd file in the R folder, and have a user level function that reads in the data and knits it.

```
# create_doc.R
create_doc <- function(directory = NULL,
                       database_name_name) {
    if (is.null(directory)) directory <- tclvalue(tkchooseDirectory(
                       title = "Choose Folder for Input and Output"))
    rmarkdown::render("R/doc_generator.Rmd", output_dir = directory)
}
```

This works fine on my computer, but when I build the package, the .Rmd file has been deleted. This means I can't give it to other users for use on other computers. I realise that the R folder may not be the correct place for this file (I guess it deletes any files not ending in .R), but I'm not sure where else to put it. It is not package documentation, it creates the end result when using the package.

Googling has not helped so far. Is it possible to knit a document using a function in an R package? If yes, what am I doing wrong. If no, are there any other suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Put the Rmd file in a `./inst/` directory. http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/inst.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include RMarkdown file in r package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377213/how-to-include-rmarkdown-file-in-r-package)