# How to create dynamic r markdown reports from r package

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to create a function in my r-package that kind of looks like this:

```
mypackage::render_github_overview(username, repo, output = "/tmp/testDir/test.html")
```

This should then generate a directory containing the Rmd and the output (either html or pdf). The pseudo-content would look something like:

```
## Overview for Repository <repository>

User <user> has <n_repos> repos with <n_stars> stars
```

Now my questions are:

1. How to pass arguments to the R markdown.
2. Where to store the template R markdown

Regarding 1.: I think the solution might be a parameterized R Markdown document and then calling `rmarkdown::render(param1...)` with the parameters.

Regarding 2 my doubts are where to store the R markdown template where the gaps will be filled in. From this answer here ([How to include RMarkdown file in r package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377213/how-to-include-rmarkdown-file-in-r-package)) I assume it could be in `R/inst/rmd/template.Rmd` or something like this. Or is there any better location?

Answer (score 3):

You should put your rmd file in `inst/rmd/template.Rmd`. Then render it using a code like this:

```
rmarkdown::render(
   input = paste0(system.file(package = "mypackage"), "/rmd/template.Rmd"),
   output_file = template.pdf,
   params = list(x1 = firstParam, x2 = secondParam, data = yourData),
   encoding     = 'UTF-8'
   )
```

About your parameters: put them at the beginning of your rmd file, like this:

```
---
title: "your title"
author: name 
output: beamer_presentation
params:
  x1 : firstParam
  x2 : secondParam
  data : yourData
---
```