# Rmd: \input LaTeX equivalent

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

## LaTeX function

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\input{folder/file.tex}
\end{document}
```

`\input{folder/file.tex}` command in LaTeX fetches the text in the file from the folder. When the main file is run, all the text from `file.tex` is compiled and included.

## Rmd - desired output

I am using R Markdown for my project. I desire to develop and document different topics in different files.

I want to have the following directory structure:

```
main.Rmd
main_directory
    code
        file1.Rmd
        file2.Rmd
    figures
    data
    read_me
```

## Explored pathways

I have explored the following routes to achieve this.

As suggested in [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30377213/how-to-include-rmarkdown-file-in-r-package)

```
sys.source(file = file.path(getwd(), "main_directory", 
                        "code", 
                        "file1.r"))
```

Here, the code text is not included in the output HTML knit from the Rmd.

- As suggested in [Link 2](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html#)

````
```{r, child=file.path(getwd(), "main_directory", "code", "file1.Rmd"}
```
````

It led to the following error:

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

Here, the code text is not included in the output HTML knit from the Rmd.

- As suggested in [Link 3](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/include.html)

````
```{r}
includeMarkdown(file.path(getwd(), "main_directory", "code", "file1.Rmd"))
```
````

It also led to the following error:

```
Error: attempt to use zero-length variable name
```

### Question: How to include the Rmd code into main file similar to LaTeX input

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the LaTeX `\input{"/path/to/file"}` is:

````
```{r include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(readr)
cat(readr::read_file("/path/to/file"))
```
````

If you want to keep the section structure and parse code chunks, use the `knit_child()` function:

````
```{r include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(knitr)
cat(knitr::knit_child("/path/to/file.Rmd", quiet = TRUE))
```
````

For many input files you can consider loading `readr` of `knitr` at the beginning, together with the definition of some `input_myfile()` function. I hope this helps!